# Flickering UI while change page in jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm using jQuery mobile 1.0. when I move to one page to another page in iPhone, the second page comes and flicker then showing first page and completely move to second page. How fix this one? thanks in advance..

Update: you can check http://gugl.org/page1.html for an example.

Comment: Your question is absolutely unanswerable like this. You give no information about the browser or device used, nothing about the code used, or if there is any other JavaScript involved.

Comment: yes, I tested in iPhone. back edn code was developed in javascript.

Comment: Please edit your question, maybe add some example code you're using, errors, etc...

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue. When going from one page to another (using AJAX), the transition completes, there's a quick displaying of the previous page, and then it finally shows the new page again.

Comment: For a question to be answerable, it needs a [minimal test case](http://sscce.org/) (complete, concise, representative sample code). See ["Writing the Perfect Question"](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) for more guidelines.

Comment: @outis : good point. I think that this is minimal test case which breaks: http://gugl.org/page1.html

Comment: @LeonFedotov: see the gugl.org/page1.html link

Comment: @Roman, is the issue happening even if you use the default jqm css instead of rtl css?.

Comment: @user700284 : not sure about that.

Comment: Have this issue with JQM 1.2 as well.

Answer (score 3):

I fix this issue with the following CSS code:

```
.ui-mobile-viewport-transitioning,
.ui-mobile-viewport-transitioning .ui-page {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

I mention more of it in [my blog](http://zsprawl.com/iOS/2012/05/fixing-the-page-flicker-during-css-slide/).

Answer (score 2):

Please let me know if the following helps with your flicker:

```
/* Remove flicker on Android / WebKit  */
.ui-page {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

This snippet comes with a warning though. While it might solve the flickering problem, it often introduces other issues.

For example I was stuck for a week trying to figure out why my google maps were no longer working the way I needed them to, and it turned out that this snippet was the cause of the problem. I moved to selectively targeting this rule to all pages that do not have maps in them.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't help :( I've seen this solution on the web. It solves another problem and with Android, rather than iPhone. As a workaround I settled with disabling animations. But I'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: Thanks, that helped my issue where the transitions were flickering only while in full screen mode on the iPad. Still a slight flicker on initial load but a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

I'd hold off for [jQueryMobile version 1.1](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/01/10/upcoming-releases-1-0-1-1-1-and-beyond/) which is due later this month.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to enable `touchOverflowEnabled`

Example:

```
<script>
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
  $.support.touchOverflow = true;
  $.mobile.touchOverflowEnabled = true;
});
</script>
```

Also note that this won't be necessary in jqm 1.1.0.  More on [this here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/touchoverflow.html).

Answer (score 0):

This behavior can be caused by quite a few items.

- Long data lists that go past the initial screen scroll. They need
  time to render when the screen scrolls
- Dynamic injection of data - same thing needs time to render
- Android seems to be flicker everywhere. The one thing we did was to      just shut off transitions for pages with android and default
  them to     fade. In fact this is the approach that JQM will be
  taking in the       next release.
- Use of non ajax based page links which than go back to your core app

These are just a few things that can cause the behaviors you may be seeing. At the very least this is a starting point to trouble shooting some of your issues.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works better for you:

```
http://jquerymobile.com/test/
```

This is a known problem with version 1 & this was reported as a closed bug for iOS. This has been worked on, and will be officially released in 1.1.

In the meantime, the test site has the latest code if you cannot wait.

(usual disclaimer about about using test code in production here.)

update: Announcing jQuery Mobile 1.1.0 RC1 
http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/02/28/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-1-0-rc1/

Demo it at:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/

Comment: Hmm... not only the 1.1-rc1 changed the default transition to 'fade', it's impossible to get 'slide' back. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/commit/5da1f11c4b90965484dd71a61867528c4718c593

Comment: You should be able to override according to the docs, otherwise change it at the link you provided. :)